# Change button text using javascript, depending on the class used by the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a dark / light theme on my website using [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#aa-using-server-side-scripts). The two color schemes are specified as classes in CSS and applied/changed on the body using javascript). Js selects the theme automatically depending on the OS' preference, or through manual input triggered by a button (which then overrides the OS' settings). The preference is then saved to localStorage. Because I'm using a button to change between the themes manually, I'd like to change the text on it accordingly - "Dark Mode" when class="light-mode" is applied on the body in order to change to the dark theme, and "Light Mode" as the buttons' text when class="dark-mode" is applied.

I'm still learning javascript. Following is what I came up with:

```js
    if (document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")) {
      document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML="Light Mode";
    } else if (document.body.classList.contains("light-theme") {
      document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML="Dark Mode";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body class="dark-theme">
  
  <button class="btn-toggle" id="theme-btn">Dark Mode</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I figured, this could do the trick (compare if class applied to the body is "dark-theme", if yes: change button text using the button's id to "Light Mode", doing the opposite if "light-theme" is applied).

Following is the html I have in use now (working as far as applying dark / light mode goes), including the script that applies the CSS classes to the body:

```js
/* Color theme picker implementation javascript */

    const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle"); /* Select the button */
    const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"); /* Check for dark mode preference at the OS level*/

    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme"); /* Get the user's theme preference from local storage, if it's available */
    if (currentTheme == "dark") { /* If the user's preference in localStorage is dark... */
      document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme"); /* ...let's toggle the .dark-theme class on the body */
    } else if (currentTheme == "light") { /* Otherwise, if the user's preference in localStorage is light... */
      document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme"); /* ...let's toggle the .light-theme class on the body */
    }

    btn.addEventListener("click", function () { /* Listen for a click on the button */
    if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) { /* If the user's OS setting is dark and matches our .dark-mode class... */
      document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme"); /* ...then toggle the light mode class */
      var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme") /* ...but use .dark-mode if the .light-mode class is already on the body, */
        ? "light"
        : "dark";
    } else {
      document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme"); /* Otherwise, let's do the same thing, but for .dark-mode */
      var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")
        ? "dark"
        : "light";
    }
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme); /* Finally, let's save the current preference to localStorage to keep using it */
    });
```

```css
/* Default colors */
body {
  --text-color: #000000;
  --bkg-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Dark theme colors */
body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #ffffff;
  --bkg-color: #000000;
}

/* Styles for users who prefer dark mode at the OS level */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body {
    --text-color: #ffffff;
    --bkg-color: #000000;
  }
  /* Override dark mode with light mode styles if the user decides to swap */
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: #000000;
    --bkg-color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
</head>

<body class="body">
  
  <button class="btn-toggle">Dark Mode</button>

</body>
```

I'd really appreciate if someone had any inputs on what route to go or a better idea on how to achieve this. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is used to retrieve elements that have a specific class. If you want to check if an element has a specific class, use [`.classList.contains(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). In your case, it should be `document.body.classList.contains('dark-theme')`

Comment: Thanks! Should have studied the documentation better. With the correct function, I've got the script to _somewhat_ work using `.classList.contains()`(see the answer I posted). Sadly, my original approach is not the way to go about this... as both classes I'm checking for are applied, the code won't get what I want :/

Answer (score 1):

I got the whole thing to work... somewhat. My solution is pretty hacky, and doesn't work completely. Below is what I got.
The issue with my first try in the answer, is that both classes, "light-mode" *and* "dark-mode" are found in the body's classList, just not... "applied"? As long as I don't find a js-method to check which class is "active", this approach won't work - because both conditions if/else are always true, so the if-clause gets always executed.

So... I got the easiest (and most convoluted) set of functions to do what I wanted to achieve. Basically, the script checks localStorage to see if a theme has already been saved, and if so, applies the correct button-text. Then, the if-else-statement is executed again on every time the button is clicked (the same if/else-clause is in the code *twice*, is there any better way to go about this?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn-toggle" id="theme-btn">Change Theme</button>
  <script>
    /* Change "theme-btn".innerHTML depending on color theme in localStorage */
    if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark") {
      document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
    } else if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "light") {
      document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
    }
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() { /* Listen to Event-change in button and check localStorage for change in theme */
      if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark") {
        document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
      } else if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == "light") {
        document.getElementById("theme-btn").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Together with the rest of my site, this works fine. Only problem is, when there's no key yet stored in localStorage, the correct text is not applied. Thus, this solution only works until after the button is clicked manually... and doesn't work for new visitors.

Looking for a different solution, I figured there could be another approach - check the OS' preference first, and then listen to the button-click. Sadly, I failed miserably - I'll document what I tried tomorrow.